# Display Text only in PDP Page

Tags: wishlist, magento2.4.5, pwa, react, react-js

We wanted to add a text **ADD TO WISHLIST** after **Add to favourites** icon in PDP Page, so We added in

src/components/wishlist/AddtoListbutton/addtoListButton.ce.js

```
return (
        <button ref={buttonRef} className={buttonClass} {...ariaButtonProps}>
            {props.icon} ADD TO WISHLIST
        </button>
    );
```

src/components/ProductFullDetail - ProductFullDetail.js

```
<Suspense fallback={null}>
   <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} />
</Suspense>
```

**Issue** : The Text is displaying in every part of the website. but we need text only in PDP Page

Here is PDP Page code - ProductFullDetail.js : https://pastebin.com/bjwKkR7k  and Wishlistbutton full code : https://pastebin.com/iSYd2ux3

**Requirement**

Is there any condition we can keep so that the "ADD TO WISHLIST" text should display only in PDP Page ?

**PDP Page** :

[image]

**Other Pages** :

[image]

Comment: Hello can you please give me a category list page and pdp page link so I have checked

Comment: @RohitGohel  Here is [PDP link](https://frontend1.staging.glowjewels.com/dreamy-wonder-diamond-necklace) , if you scroll down below in PDP, you can see `Trending around you`

Comment: Okay i will check and update if I have get any solution

Comment: @mohitvamja thankyou very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one solution for your issue, I have solved this issue using the CSS method not any conditional and logical method below I have added steps to solve this issue if you are okay with going with CSS then apply it your issue will solved.

**First,**
add a span tag to the addToListButton.ce.js, replace your return statement with this code

```
return (
    <button ref={buttonRef} className={buttonClass} {...ariaButtonProps}>
        {props.icon} <span className='only-pdp'>{buttonText}</span>
    </button>
);
```

**Second,**
remove this CSS into your CSS file

```
.addToListButton-root-n63 {
    min-height: 2rem;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(199, 164, 111) 0%, rgb(136, 108, 68) 100%);
    width: 72%;
    height: 40px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

**Third,**
Add this new CSS to your CSS file

```
.addToListButton-root-n63 .only-pdp {
    display: none;
}
.productFullDetail-productDesc-HUd .addToListButton-root-n63 .only-pdp {
    display: block;
}
.productFullDetail-productDesc-HUd .addToListButton-root-n63 {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(199, 164, 111) 0%, rgb(136, 108, 68) 100%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.productFullDetail-productDesc-HUd .addToListButton-root-n63 .icon-icon-P1l {
    stroke: #fff;
}
.productFullDetail-productDesc-HUd .addToListButton-root-n63:hover{
    background: rgb(199, 164, 111, 0.8) !important;
}
```

Please apply this step and check whether the solution is working or not.

Comment: This is good, it's working, i am trying to add css to text `{buttonText}` and i used   `.only-pdp` , but the css is not adding.  here is css file :  https://pastebin.com/CeJTXwL0  i am also checking

Comment: I have used the same CSS in my console and it's working see here - https://prnt.sc/9mvGX9atWzXN

Comment: please tell for which class you added the code ? i added for `.only-pdp`

Comment: yes I have added only one class otherwise all CSS classes are already in the default Magento

Comment: okay, did you added all style codes in `.only-pdp` , or can you send me your console screenshot ?

Comment: .only-pdp class is not loading for me : https://prnt.sc/I13I4W0098jo

Comment: please remove this CSS into your CSS file not need to add this CSS - https://prnt.sc/1PbcH-Ripxqf and add only this CSS which I have mentioned in the answer - https://prnt.sc/eng8QtXuVGr4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151035/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-rohit-gohel).